# Extracting the javascript from an anchor's href using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Does anyone know an easy way to use jQuery (or other Javascript if necessary) to extract only the Javascript portion of an anchor tag's href attribute (like the one below), so it can be assigned to another event at runtime?

```
<a id="FancyLink" href="javascript:DoSomething('Input1')">Do</a>
```

I know how to get the anchor's whole attribute value using jQuery, and I suppose I could just do that and then chop off the "javascript:" prefix manually, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to obtain a JavaScript function object from the above example.

Thanks for the help!

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var code = $('#FancyLink').attr('href').replace(/^javascript:\s*/, '');
```

This will return a stringm which you'll need to `eval` in order to execute.
For better performance, you can call `eval` once and create a function, like this:

```
var executor = eval('[ function() { ' + code + ' } ]')[0];
```

The array is necessary because IE cannot directly return a function from `eval`.

For even better performance, don't do this at all.

Comment: This looks great!  I will try it and let you know.  Thanks much for the superfast response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't refactor the `<a href="javascript:...">`  code, which is the problem here, you could also assign the href to `location`, which is roughly what happens when user clicks the link anyway. That would save you chopping off the 'javascript:' portion and would be a bit more natural.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I need to do this is that I don't have control over the JavaScript placed in the href.  It is generated by other software, and I want a clean way of parsing it out.

Comment: @BrianFinkel: note that I assumed that and suggested a way to use the href without parsing the 'javascript:' portion out.

Comment: Sorry, Nickolay, but I still don't understand your suggestion.  What do you mean when you say I could assign href to 'location'?  'location' is not an attribute of the href tag, and I don't know what you are referring to.  How does your answer help me to extract the JavaScript portion of the href attribute as cleanly as possible?

Comment: @BrianFinkel: location = a.href. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: example (copy/paste to Firefox location bar): data:text/html,<a id="link" href="javascript:alert(1)">test</a><script>function onload () {location = document.getElementById("link").href}</script>

Comment: So you are suggesting that I copy the contents of the anchor's href attribute to the brower's location field in order to have the browser remove the "javascript:" prefix for me?  I'm probably not going to do that, but thank you for the lateral suggustion.